# specialize template<typename T, template<typename> class U>

Tags: c++, templates

I have a problem with nested templates and their template specialization. Given the following classes:

A small template class

```
template<class U>
class T {
public:
    T(){}
    virtual ~T (){}

};
```

And some kind of nested template

```
template<typename T, template<typename> class U>
class A {
public:
    void foo() 
    { 
        std::cerr << "A generic foo"; 
    }
};
```

And a small main.cpp

```
int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    A<int,T> *a = new A<int,T>;
    a->foo();

    //This wont work:
    A<double,T*> *b = new A<double,T*>;
    b->foo();

    return 0;
}
```

Now I need a specialization if U is a pointer:

```
    A<double,T*> *b = new A<double,T*>;
    b->foo();
```

How to achieve this? I tried something like:

```
template<typename T, template<typename> class U>
class A< T, U* >
{
public:
void foo()
{
    std::cerr << "A specialized foo";
}
};
```

But it just resolves in

```
A.h:18:16: Error: Templateargument 2 is invalid
```

Comment: You seem to be confused.

Comment: @ildjarn: no, that's fine, because `A` expects something that is a template type with one parameter. `T` fits that bill.

Comment: @bitmask : Ah, totally correct, I apparently wasn't paying attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're tying to do is not possible, because `T*` has no meaning. Neither is it a proper type, nor does it match a template, which requires additional parameters. If `U` were to represent `T*`, what would `U<int>` be? You probably mean `T<int>*` but that doesn't match your declaration, so there is no way to plug that type into `A`.

Since you asked for a way to get around this, from the top of my head, something like this.

Accept a third template argument to `A`, which I would call `Expander` and set it by default to this:

```
template <typename T> struct Expander {
  typedef T type;
};
```

Then, when invoking `A` you could say

```
A<int,T> normal;
A<int,T,PtrExpander> pointer;
```

with

```
template <typename T> struct PtrExpander {
  typedef T* type;
};
```

and `A` would be:

```
template<typename T, template<typename> class U, template <typename> class E = Expander> class A {
  typedef typename E<U<Your_Args_to_U> >::type;
```

Comment: But T does represent a template, doesnt it?

Comment: @user988017: Yes, but `T*` doesn't. Since `T` is not a type (it's a template) you cannot have a pointer to it. C++ *could* allow you this informal notation, but it doesn't.

Comment: I see... what's the easiest way to get around this?